# How to find the difference between multiple files

Tags: linux, file, unix, compare, diff

I have an application installed in 20 linux servers. The application contains multiple configuration files such as.

```
/etc/config_1/config_1_1.cfg
/etc/config_1/config_1_2.cfg
/etc/config_2/config_2_1.cfg
/etc/config_2/config_2_2.cfg
/etc/config_3/config_3.cfg
```

I will have all these configuration files in all the servers. Now, I wanna compare and find the difference between the config files in all the servers.

Eg:
Compare `/etc/config_1/config_1_1.cfg` between server1, server2 and server3  etc..

Answer (score 0):

From command line:

`vim -d /etc/config_1/config_1_1.cfg /etc/config_1/config_1_2.cfg /etc/config_2/config_2_1.cfg /etc/config_2/config_2_2.cfg /etc/config_3/config_3.cfg`

Comment: I hope vim -d will work for only 4 files, I have to compare 20 files.

Comment: I have never had a use case to compare 20 files, but you can give a try. In that case you most probably will need a wide screen to fit 20 views opened at one window, but technically I would not expect some limitation of VIM to handle this.

Comment: I just tried that and discovered vim has a a limit of 8 files.

Answer (score 0):

When you are only interested in the values, you can do something like

```
grep "." allfiles | sed 's/^\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/\2 : \1/' | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to collect the files in the same location to be easier and execute the following command:

```
diffuse x.cfg y.cfg
```

this will give you the ability to highlight the diffrence

Answer (score -2):

Using the file comparison tool.

Comment: can you suggest some tool that can compare 20 files at a time